# Подскажите API для работы с погодой

Tags: python, api, requests

Недавно начал изучать requests python, хочу с помощью этой библиотеки получить погоду. Можете подсказать сайты с таким API.

Comment: https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis

Answer (score 2):

Weather, Яндекс.Погода, Gismeteo и множество других. У всех разные условия, гуглите и найдете подходящее

Comment: А вариант с парсингом будет работать?

Comment: Что в вашем понимании парсинг? Спарсить можно любой JSON формат, из которых в большинстве случаем состоит API сайтов

Comment: с помощью beautifulsoup

Comment: Быть может эта [статья](https://lavrynenko.com/parsing-dannyx-s-pomoshhyu-beautifulsoup/) поможет

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылка откуда я беру данные.

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&units=metric&appid={api}&lang=ru
```